# Which division is Tilly now in?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

When I watched the season finale of season 3 of *Star Trek: Discovery*, during the final season on the bridge, Tilly is in sciences blue. If you look at the screenshot [on this page:](https://thespool.net/reviews/tv/recap/star-trek-discovery-season-3-finale-recap/) (you'll need to scroll down).

Tilly is in command red. In the latter part of that scene when they pan by the bridge crew, when paused the science blue of Tilly's uniform looks as if it was photoshopped in. Has there been anything to indicate which division she's actually meant to be in (command red or sciences blue)?

It makes me wonder if they decided right at the very last minuet to change what division she's in (plus also you can't see the whole of her comm badge so there's no way to tell if she's been promoted).

Comment: Canonically she's Science Division since that's what we see in the episode. It will be interesting to see why it was changed.

Comment: "you can't see the whole of her comm badge" - the comm badge is fully visible a little later, if slightly blurry, while Tilly just finishes her summary of Discovery's new orders. It looks like there is only one filled pip in there, which would probably indicate she's an Ensign.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz it's weird as if she's still acting XO then she should be in command red. She's an engineer so if she's not now acting XO then she should be in engineering/operations yellow. I'm wondering if she's now Chief Science Officer

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: Spock was first officer and wore blue, Data was second officer and wore yellow (although I think he did switch to red in an alternate reality/timeline when he became the first officer (?)). Quite possibly, specialized responsibilities (such as being the chief science officer) trump "mere administrative roles" when it comes to uniform colors. Also, there may be a similar confusion as with Stamets: He's *not* an engineer, rather a biologist, but the showrunners repeatedly seemed to forget about that when writing his scenes (or at least, he is equally skilled in engineering ...

Comment: ... as in biology and could equally well fulfil all the duties of an engineer).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Data wore red once in the prime timeline, the two parter when Captain Jellicoe took command of the Enterprise (Riker got relived of duty)

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: Ah, you're right. But then, Jellico did strike me as the chain-of-command type, anyway ;)

Comment: A nice touch with that episode is at the end when Discovery arrives back at Federation HQ. The other ships form an honour guard for Discovery

Comment: several of these comments are conflating TOS colors w/ TNG colors. Colors were switched around in the TNG era. Discovery is in TOS era..until it's...not...and in the 31st century

Comment: @NKCampbell if you look at the screen shot those in operations/engineering are wearing yellow, sciences, blue, medical white, and command, red. You're forgetting that they're now in the future AFTER the era when TNG is set

Comment: did I forget that? I specifically mentioned the 31st century :)

Comment: @NKCampbell they're in the year 3189 which is way past the TNG era and nowhere near the TOS era ;)

Comment: ...ok...I addressed that. thanks.

Comment: I've seen a few mentions around that Tilly has been promoted to lieutenant. Can't do a screen grab from Netflix to zoom in on from the scene where she's reading out the list of stops for their first supply runs, as that's the best bet for seeing how many pips are actually on her comm badge

Comment: Trailer now out for season 4 and Tilly is in sciences blue so I think it's safe to say she's definitely in the sciences division. Can't get a clear image of her com badge but it looks possibly like just one pip so it appears that she's still an ensign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[They did recolor Tilly's uniform in post-production.](https://twitter.com/xforce11/status/1347914951285944321?s=20)

Several people have speculated that they want to keep their options open for Tilly's role in Season 4. There's precedent for science-section uniforms in the first officer role (e.g. Spock in TOS) so she may well remain first officer/XO.